# radare2 not showing function names

Tags: radare2

I'm using radare2 and I've noticed that it simply prints function offsets rather than function names.

I've done some tests and I've discovered that on Kali it prints offsets and on debian it prints names.

Here you can see how r2 behaves in Kali:
[image: raadre2 on kali linux showing only call 0x0ffset]

It is, for example, printing `call 0x4ce645` insted of `call reloc.puts_WhatEver`. When I inspect ELF properties, I can see that function names are indeed located at that offset.
[image: readelf -r]

I don't really know what is making r2 behave that way. Here is some info about Kali environment I'm using.
[image: kali environment settings]

On the other hand, when using r2 on Debian and debugging the exact same file I can prefectly see function names.

[image: function name printing in debian]

Here is some info about Debian environment I'm using.
[image: Debian environment settings]

The file I'm debugging in both Kali and Debian is exactly the same.
[image]
[image]

How could I get r2 to behave in Kali exactly the same way it is behaving in Debian?

Comment: Do you use the latest version of radare2? To check, please share the output of `r2 -v`. The latest version is 2.6. Such bugs are sometimes caused by old version of r2. If this is the case, do not use radare2 version from your distribution's repositories (i.e `apt-get install radare2`), hence the differences you see. Use the latest version from git or at least the last release. See installation instructions [here](https://github.com/radare/radare2).

Comment: Hello @Megabeets, turns out I have installed r2 2.7 version in Kali (missworking) and r2 2.4 version in Debian (properly working) IMG: https://ibb.co/dYL4mo

Comment: I love when new version has regression not catched from dev team.

Comment: @Razvi so it might be a bug. Please [open an issue](https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/new) in the radare2 Github repository, describing the problem.